# Does Awareness (mastery) increase the XP gained from Sage (mastery)?

Tags: league-of-legends

I would like to know if the mastery [Awareness](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Awareness_%28Season_Two_Mastery%29) increases the exp bonus gained by the mastery [Sage](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_%28Season_Two_Mastery%29).  Although the experience gained isn't exactly a game-changing difference, I'm still curious.

Comment: For future reference, putting filler in is generally frowned upon. Perhaps you could insert a blockquote showing exactly what the Awareness and Sage masteries do?

Comment: @Fluttershy please clarify, what do you mean by 'filler'?

Comment: @Ender Check the revision history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short yes it stacks.
[Sage](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_%28Season_Two_Mastery%29) gives a set bonus of 40 exp(20 in Crystal Scar) for kills and assists.  Once the total exp amount is calculated(including Sage's bonus) the bonus from [Awareness](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Awareness_%28Season_Two_Mastery%29) and/or Zilean's [Heightened Learning](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zilean#Heightened_Learning) is added on.  So potentially, with all 3 that 40exp could turn into 45.2exp!

Note: These masteries no longer exist in the current game